# How can I make a certain program always minimize to tray?

Tags: windows, notification-area

I would like to be able to set a certain program to always minimize to the system tray when I click the minimize button in the title bar. I've found programs that would accomplish this using extra menus or keyboard shortcuts, but this isn't what I'm looking for - I want it to work when clicking on the minimize button.

Is there a program that could help me accomplish this?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: [Tray Everything](https://superuser.com/questions/1008545/how-can-i-make-a-certain-program-always-minimize-to-tray) works for me.

Comment: Isn't that where minimized programs go?  Why do you need a special tool?

Comment: @fixer1234 I want them to minimize to the system tray: http://i.imgur.com/lVvzSpS.png

Comment: Where do they minimize now?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Looks like you somehow grabbed the link for this page instead of the product link.

Comment: @fixer1234 They minimize to the left area of the taskbar of course. http://i.imgur.com/lWntmiN.jpg I want that program to minimize to the tray (notification area), so that I can hide it from view and from the alt+tab queue when i'm not using it.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 Corrected link [Tray Everything](http://tray-everything.en.uptodown.com/)

Comment: @Andreyu Corrected link [Tray Everything](http://tray-everything.en.uptodown.com/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the suggestion (The link still doesn't work, maybe SuperUser is removing it?). I downloaded Tray Everything and tried it but sadly it doesn't seem to work with my program (which is a Chrome standalone app - maybe that's the problem).

In the meantime I found a software that works - 4T Tray Minimizer, but only in the paid version, which is $20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [RBTRay](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/) but it requires right-click instead and I don't think that would be much of a problem.

Source: [HowToGeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27007/whats-the-simplest-way-to-minimize-applications-to-the-system-tray/)

Comment: Thanks, RBTray is good enough. I originally wanted a left-click solution but yeah, it's not too much of a problem.